# Loading jquerymobile website from mobile device

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, browser

I have made a Web page with jQuery mobile, and have uploaded the page to my web server, but when I load the page from my iPhone, it loads the page as it would be a "desktop website". It looks like jquery mobile does not recognize that the page is being loaded from a mobile device. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site? It's hard to tell what's going on without example code or a link to preview the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this viewport to your html head:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

If you want more info about screen sizing take a look at this link: http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/rrobinson/archive/2011/07/25/how-to-scale-a-jquery-mobile-site-for-ios.aspx